# how does EntrySet instance works in the HashMap?

Tags: java, dictionary

I'd like to find out how the EntrySet instance works in the HashMap.
And I use the code below,I try to see what the instance exactly is,

And the entryset is an instance of EntrySet.

```
system.out.println(entryset);
```

It prints out the whole map's message,how does this work?

Thanks.

Comment: Try having a look into the source code. And: try to come up with more clear questions. And please: mind the "casing". You keep using lowercase where uppercase would be needed; and vice versa. Several times. That doesnt help with making your question any clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HashMap.EntrySet` inherits its [toString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString()) method from `AbstractCollection` :

> Returns a string representation of this collection. The string
>   representation consists of a list of the collection's elements in the
>   order they are returned by its iterator, enclosed in square brackets
>   ("[]"). Adjacent elements are separated by the characters ", " (comma
>   and space). Elements are converted to strings as by
>   String.valueOf(Object).

As you see, it iterates over all the entries and basically calls their `toString` method (`valueOf` calls `toString` on the `Object`), and separates them with comma (and space).

Then, look at the `toString` method of `HashMap.Entry`  :

```
public final String toString() {
            return getKey() + "=" + getValue();
        }
```

As you see, it displays both the key and the value.

So a call to `System.out.println(entryset);` will print the entire content of the `HashMap`.

Answer (score 1):

My opion is there is not a real EntrySet element in the HashMap,it means there is not a copy of a HashMap for the EntrySet

The methods of the EntrySet just use the elements of the HashMap to handle messages in the 'Set' way.

And the tostring method in the EntrySet is just been overriden to show the map's elements,the result is not from the EntrySet instance.

last edition

---

I think the method tostring() is overrided to print out the map's message

Comment: And I think that would hardly make a valid comment; yet alone a decent answer. Sorry,.